# how to integrate automapper in asp.net core web api from many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I have an entity user

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public  ICollection<UsersClasses> UsersClasses { get; set; }
}
```

and another entity Userclass

```
public class UserClass
{
    public int UserClassId  { get; set; }
    public string UserClassName { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<UsersClasses> UsersClasses { get; set; }

}
```

between them many to many relationship as

```
public class UsersClasses
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public UserClass UserClass { get; set; }
    public int  UserClassId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map "UserClassName" form "UserClass" to be filled in user.

I try to add filed class in userTolistDto name with className hope to map with userclassname and thanks like this and working this not working.

```
CreateMap<User, UserForListDto>()
    .ForMember(dest=>dest.ClassName , opt=> {
opt.MapFrom(src=>src.UsersClasses.UserClass.UserClassName);
});
```

Comment: Your classes are so confusing, you have a class named: `UserClass` and another class named `UserClasses`! (The recommended way of naming your entities is not to pluralize the entity names)... also you have not included `UserForListDto` in your question.

Comment: userForListDto beside feilds another filed name classname with i want to be mapped with userclassname but i cannot to do that